# Dart/Flutter: jsonDecode() loses precision when converting Java Long to Dart int from a Json String

Tags: json, dart, long-integer

Summary:
I am sending a Json String from Android Java side to Flutter Dart side. I use jsonDecode() to parse the Json String, but the Long type number will be converted to int and lose precision. I want Java Long type to be parsed to a Dart String or BigInt before jsonDecode() think it is an int.

In detail:
I am writing a Dart plugin which gets a Json String from Android Java code. In my Android code, it's a String that can be converted to JSONObject which supports the Long type. I send this string to Dart side. The string looks like this:

```
{
  "myList": [
    {"longNum": 1234567890123401352},
    {"longNum": 1234567890123450168},
    {"longNum": 1234567890123452213}
  ],
  "secondList": "other stuff"
}
```

I try to jsonDecode() this string in order to get my 'longNum', but it seems that jsonDecode() would automatically convert it to int and will lose precision.

Here is my testing code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var a = '''{
      "myList": [
        {
          "longNum": 1234567890123401352
        },
        {
          "longNum": 1234567890123450168
        },
        {
          "longNum": 1234567890123452213
        }
      ],
      "secondList": "Other stuff... Is regex an elegant solution to parse 1234567890123401352 here?"
    }''';
  Map aMap = jsonDecode(a);
  print(aMap.toString());
}
```

Console log:

```
{myList: [{longNum: 1234567890123401500}, {longNum: 1234567890123450000}, {longNum: 1234567890123452200}], secondList: other stuff}
```

I would like to find a way to auto parse int to String/BigInt.
I searched the Internet but found the only way is that it should originally be a String, then I can BigInt.parse() the number. Is there other way to do in the Dart side so I can parse it to String or BigInt type without making jsonDecode() think it is an int? For example, rewrite jsonDecode(myStr) to jsonDecode(myStr, String)?

Otherwise, I will have to convert this string to JSONObject and revise the int to String in Android side, and then send JSONObject.toString() to Dart. I think if later I get a json string from the other side like an API call from server, then it might not work any more. Therefore I would like to know if there is a better way to do in the Dart side.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you're storing large integers, you probably would be better off storing them in JSON as strings instead for interoperability with JavaScript.  From there you can manually use `BigInt.parse`.

Comment: Will tell my colleague not to send serial number as an int next time :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want Java Long type to be parsed to a Dart String or BigInt before jsonDecode() think it is an int.

That's not what `jsonDecode` does. It decodes JSON numbers to Dart numbers.

If you want to parse differently, you'll have to parse the JSON yourself, or replace the literals with strings (you can probably use a RegExp to surround digits with quotes) *before* parsing using `jsonDecode`.

However, if you are running on a native platform, you *shouldn't need* that, because a Dart `int` is a 64-bit number, just like a Java `long`,
and the numbers in your example should be parsed correctly.

Your problem suggests that you are running on the web, where all Dart numbers are JavaScript numbers (which means `double`s), with at most 53 bits of precision. The web Dart compilation uses the JavaScript `JSON.parse` so it does what JavaScript does.

In that case, maybe converting big numbers to strings is a good idea.
Maybe:

```dart
final _jsonLiterals = RegExp(
    r'"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|((?<![eE.\d+\-])[+\-]?\d{16,}(?![\d.eE]))');
String quoteBigInts(String jsonSource) =>
  jsonSource.replaceAllMapped(_jsonLiterals, (m) {
    var digits = m[1];
    if (digits != null) return '"$digits"';
    return m[0]!;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between running on a native platform and the web! This confused me because I tested it well on my mobile side (in VS Code console) but the web side turned out to be different (testing partial code on DartPad). Regex may be a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.
This is a json parser and hooks for postprocessing.

```dart
import 'package:parser_combinator/extra/json_parser.dart' as json_parser;
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser_combinator.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parsing.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/runtime.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/tracing.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  bool fastParse<O>(Parser<String, O> parser, State<String> state) {
    return parser.fastParse(state);
  }

  String? number;
  Result<O>? parse<O>(Parser<String, O> parser, State<String> state) {
    final pos = state.pos;
    final result = parser.parse(state);
    if (parser.name == '_number') {
      if (result != null) {
        number = state.input.substring(pos, state.pos);
      }
    } else if (parser.name == '_value') {
      if (number != null) {
        final value = number;
        number = null;
        // Or use BigNum here...
        return Result(value as O);
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  final builder = TracerBuilder(
      fastParse: fastParse,
      parse: parse,
      filter: <O>(parser) {
        return parser.name == '_number' || parser.name == '_value';
      });
  final p = builder.build(json_parser.parser);
  const input = '''{
      "myList": [
        {
          "longNum": 1234567890123401352123456789012340135212345678901234013521234567890123450168
        },
        {
          "longNum": 1234567890123450168
        },
        {
          "longNum": 1234567890123452213
        }
      ],
      "secondList": "Other stuff... Is regex an elegant solution to parse 1234567890123401352 here?"
    }''';

  final r = parseString(p.parse, input);
  print(r);
}
```

Output:

```
{myList: [{longNum: 1234567890123401352123456789012340135212345678901234013521234567890123450168
        }, {longNum: 1234567890123450168
        }, {longNum: 1234567890123452213
        }], secondList: Other stuff... Is regex an elegant solution to parse 1234567890123401352 here?}
```