# JsonDecode in flutter lost digit

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I use post API to send request to the server and the response data hold a list of image link.

Receive the data successfully, but when decoded it lost some digits. My current link is 133 digit and after decode it loses the last 5 digits. What is wrong here? Is it limit for 128 digit?

```dart
if (response.Data != '') {
      Iterable iList = jsonDecode(response.Data);
      _list = List<String>.from(iList.map((e) => e.toString()));
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of `response.Data`?  If you're trying to parse an integer with 133 digits, that won't work.  That's far larger than what can be stored in a Dart `int`.  You should be treating it as a string instead (and parsing as `BigInt` if you really want to treat it as a number).  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/75892788/

Comment: here is the example of response data: 
http ://my-sever/712d70d3-844c-4e74-a1a9-416c2b473f468828697507038875839.jpg
It just the example my-sever is longer and totall in have 133 digit at all.
the different here is i dont covert it to map when put it on json is that the problem ?

Normal we use :  'userName' : 'David'   . But here i just put it like 'David'

Comment: I still don't understand.  Are you saying that `response.Data` is a string `'"http://my-sever/712d70d3-844c-4e74-a1a9-416c2b473f468828697507038875839.jpg"'`?  If not, what is it?  Also, it'd be better to *edit* your question to include relevant information and so that you can properly format it.

Comment: What i wanna say is. Api response.data is json string which have Map data right. But this time. I dont put it into map before send it to json. ?